# What is the word that can replace "even if it is"?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

> A: The car costs approximately $40,000. And the man told me he can get me a discount off and it would be something like $35,000.
>
> B: **Even if it is** $35,000, it still costs a lot and we will not be able to afford it.

Are there any phase/words out there that can replace *even if it is* to make it more fluid or daily-conversational? And can I use ***be it*** here?

Comment: Notwithstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use ***be it*** there.

I think ***Even if it is*** is fine and fluid.

But some other fine examples of how to say it could be

> Even at $35,000, it still costs a lot and we will not be able to
>   afford it.

or

> $35,000 still costs a lot and we will not be able to afford it.

or

> We will not be able to afford it, even at $35,000.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the unnecessary "if it is... it".

> Even $35,000 still costs a lot and we will not be able to afford it.

Comment: An amount of money doesn't cost anything. You can characterize the amount itself as "a lot" (or "a little" or whatever), but don't use the word "costs": *$35,000 is still more money than we can afford.*

Answer (score -2):

I would just leave it the way it is or simply take out the "even"...
   A. "If it is $35,000, it still costs a lot and we will not be able to afford it."
Just simply taking out the "even" makes the sentence much more fluid.
   B. "Even if it is 35,000, it is still expensive and we will not be able to afford it." 
However if you leave "even" in it still works

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: okay... that makes more since